# Как исключить названии класса при его сериализации в Xml

Tags: java, jackson

Имеется класс

```
public class Invertors {
  String value;    
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }    
  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }    
}
```

Перевожу его в XML

```
Invertors invertors; 
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(reques);
```

И получаю

```
<Invertors>
    <value>datard</value>
</Invertors>
```

Как мне исключить название класса при сериализации?
Чтобы получилось вот так:

```
<value>datard</value>
```